# Handle com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException inside a RequestContext

Tags: java, jackson, jersey

I'm using jackson as the json provider for jersey and I'm having some trouble. Picture the following scenario:

```
An entity have a property defined by an Enum
Someone sends a request with an invalid value for the Enum
```

Jersey will try to deserialize the request using jackson and will fail returning a 500 HTTP response. I wish to change that to a 422, since it's a client error. Where in jersey request handling could I handle this failure?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to catch the error and return another HTTP code. Example :

*MyEnum.java*

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2
}
```

*Entity.java*

```
public class Entity {

    @JsonProperty
    protected String id;

    @JsonProperty
    protected MyEnum value;

    @JsonCreator
    public Entity(
        @JsonProperty("id") String id,
        @JsonProperty("value") MyEnum value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

*WSTest.java*

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean test(final Entity entity) { // will throw com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException if the enum value is not valid
    System.out.println(entity);
    return true;
}
```

*JsonExceptionMapper.java*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class JsonExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<InvalidFormatException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(InvalidFormatException ex) {
        // TODO: log error
        return Response.status(422)
            .build();
    }
}
```

If you call **/test** with `{"id": "test", "value": "VALUE1"}` : HTTP **200**

If you call it with `{"id": "test", "value": "VALUE3"}` : HTTP **422**

Comment: If I define an ExceptionMapper, it will maps everytime the exception is thrown inside the container, right? The problem with it is the exception can be thrown outside a request context. My solution was to define another message body reader wrapping InvalidFormatException into a custom exception and writing a Mapper for it.